# Couldn't install File::Path library with cpan

Tags: perl, cpan

I am unable to install `File::Path` library using `cpan`. What is wrong?

```
# perl -v

This is perl 5, version 26, subversion 1 (v5.26.1) built for x86_64-linux

Copyright 1987-2017, Larry Wall

Perl may be copied only under the terms of either the Artistic License or the
GNU General Public License, which may be found in the Perl 5 source kit.

Complete documentation for Perl, including FAQ lists, should be found on
this system using "man perl" or "perldoc perl".  If you have access to the
Internet, point your browser at http://www.perl.org/, the Perl Home Page.

# cpan -v
/usr/bin/cpan script version 1.66, CPAN.pm version 2.18
```

Is there some other way how to make it installed or is there some workaround?

```
# cpan install File::Path
Reading '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Thu, 01 Mar 2018 13:17:03 GMT
Running install for module 'File::Path'
CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v6.01)
CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v2.074)
Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/J/JK/JKEENAN/File-Path-2.15.tar.gz ok
CPAN: YAML loaded ok (v1.24)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta::Requirements loaded ok (v2.140)
CPAN: Parse::CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.150010)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.150010)
CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v5.20180220)
Configuring J/JK/JKEENAN/File-Path-2.15.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for File::Path
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  JKEENAN/File-Path-2.15.tar.gz
  /root/localperl/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- OK
Running make for J/JK/JKEENAN/File-Path-2.15.tar.gz
cp lib/File/Path.pm blib/lib/File/Path.pm
Manifying 1 pod document
  JKEENAN/File-Path-2.15.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- OK
Running make test
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/root/localperl/bin/perl" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/Path-Class.t .. ok     
t/Path.t ........ ok       
t/Path_root.t ... 1/11 
#   Failed test 'created a directory not owned by 1:inpuu...'
#   at t/Path_root.t line 77.
#                   'unable to map inpuu to a gid, group ownership not changed:  at t/Path_root.t line 72.
# '
#     doesn't match '(?^s:unable to map 1 to a uid, ownership not changed:)'
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 11.
t/Path_root.t ... Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/11 subtests 
t/Path_win32.t .. skipped: not win32
t/taint.t ....... ok   

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/Path_root.t (Wstat: 256 Tests: 11 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  8
  Non-zero exit status: 1
Files=5, Tests=214,  2 wallclock secs ( 0.05 usr  0.01 sys +  0.36 cusr  0.09 csys =  0.51 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/5 test programs. 1/214 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
  JKEENAN/File-Path-2.15.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports JKEENAN/File-Path-2.15.tar.gz
```

Comment: Which distro ??

Comment: Centos7, Perl 5.26.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This test failure is a known problem on centos 7, try the patch on RT.

https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=121967

Comment: I have no experience with using patches. Please advise.

Comment: You could search the Web to learn how to apply a patch. You could look at the patch and figure out what the `+` and `-` in the first column mean, and edit the file manually.

Comment: It wan't that hard. I made it. Thank you!

Comment: No need to apply the patch. Since this is a bug in the test (as opposed to a bug in the module), this is one of the few times it's safe to force-install the module.